# Clear "Other" data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, storage

I know very [similar questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8456/how-can-i-clean-up-other-storage-on-iphone-3g) have been asked on [Stack Overflow.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37021/how-do-i-clear-data-listed-as-other-on-my-iphone)

Yet, 8/9 years and a couple of iOS updates later, I am wondering if there is any new solution to this problem. I currently have 14.07GB occupied on my iPhone which is more than half of its total capacity (*andere* = *other*):
[image: System usage]

I know of the following options:

- restore iPhone from Backup after wiping it
- use a third party app like [iPhone cleaner](http://www.fireebok.com/cleanmyphone.html), [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) or [DiskAid](https://imazing.com/diskaid) to dig into the files

I have deleted Safari caches, deleted music files (I am using Apple Music, so I only stream), offloaded most of my photos/videos and activated *offloading unused apps*. Yet, this wouldn't help much with the "other" data anyway...

If the mentioned options are the only ones I have, what would you advise me to do and why?

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote?

Comment: For anyone interested: Wiping the iPhone and reinstalling everything from a backup works quite good, I now have only 2GB of "other" and plenty of storage left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you sure you need to clear this data? iPhones manage the "Others" category alone and should "release" the cache when space is low.

> If the mentioned options are the only ones I have, what would you advise me to do and why?

I would choose the backup & reset option so you don't have to dig into the files and the cache will be the smallest possible.

Comment: Well, 14GB "other" on a 32GB phone is just too much. I have not even 1GB total storage left, so the iPhone *should* release the cache but it doesn't...