# My iPhone thinks there are 3.5 GB of photos but I literally have no photos there (just deleted everything!)

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, photos.app

I’m not sure why this is happening. I tried deleting my photos and emptying the deleted photos file. I also deleted all shared albums etc.  there’s literally nothing on my photo album. This issue existed before I updated to iOS 14.4.2 and persists since the update just ten minutes ago.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: iOS management of temporary/cache files can be frustrating and I think that is what this might be. Back up your iPhone to your computer (set a password so you don't lose saved passwords!) and go to `Settings > General > reset > erase all content and settings` and wipe the phone. Once that is done restore from the backup. As temporary/cache files are not backed up or restored that should do it.

Comment: i'd first just try a reboot. Sometimes it just jogs its elbow sufficiently. If not, then as Steve says.

Comment: I can confirm that @SteveChambers method does work: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382888/clear-other-data-on-iphone